# reuse cached spring contexts to build a bigger context

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-test

I have different spring tests. some of them use only entity manager and repositories but some use also other beans *and* entity manager and repositories. can I reuse the context built for db tests and build just the missing part of bigger context? and therefore avoid expensive build of entity manager again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible via a clever hierarchical structure for your contexts. Beans in any given context can *see* beans in the same context as well as beans in parent contexts.

You might not actually deploy your production application using such a hierarchy, but creating such a hierarchy in tests would allow you to avoid the performance hit of loading the JPA `EntityManager` again.

Basically, you'll be using the `@ContextHierarchy` annotation within a test class hierarchy, where the context loaded for the (potentially `abstract`) parent test class defines the bean for the `EntityManager`.

Take a look at the [Context hierarchies](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-ctx-hierarchies) section of the *Testing* chapter in the Spring Framework reference manual.

Regards,

Sam (author of the Spring TestContext Framework)